# Swift Array as a buffer... append new and delete oldest...?

Tags: swift

Is there a way to create an array that will remove the oldest item, i.e. the item first stored, and append the new one?

So if I had a limit of 1000 ...

33, 67, .... 589, 23 <--- Oldest  Append 56 and we get 56, 33, 67, .... 589

I don't know what to call it, so I can't find it.

Comment: Maybe just do `array.removeFirst(1)`

Comment: @aheze 1 is redundant `.removeFirst()`

Comment: thanks, that's all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create your own buffer class.

Here is the demo

```
class BufferArray<Element> {
    
    private var maxSize: Int = 0
    
    var arrData = [Element]()
    
    init(maxSize: Int) {
        self.maxSize = maxSize
    }
    
   func append(_ item: Element) {
        
        if self.arrData.count >= self.maxSize {
            self.arrData.removeLast()
        }
        
        self.arrData.insert(item, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Example

```
var buffer = BufferArray<Int>(maxSize: 5)

buffer.append(1)
buffer.append(2)
buffer.append(3)
buffer.append(4)
buffer.append(5)
buffer.append(6)
print(buffer.arrData)
// Output : [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to insert at 0. He just want to keep appending and removing the first object (the oldest element) as needed.

Comment: @LeoDabus here is the just example of how he can create buffere.. he/she can modify append-remove logic as per the requirement.

Comment: Why would OP need to constrain element to Equatable? Why a class? Why inherit from NSObject?

Comment: Equatable for making generic class, the class used for some storage I can also use struct. NSObject yes not required here.

Comment: Why would the generic type need to be Equatable? This doesn't make any sense. The use of a class in Swift for a collection doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: yes, I removed Equatable. but what should I need to use instead of class? struct ?

Comment: Yes a generic struct that conform to MutableCollection, RandomAccessCollection, ExpressibleByArrayLiteral, RangeReplaceableCollection and CustomStringConvertible